# Unblocking Meteor.logout and login

Tags: javascript, meteor, timeout, fiber

I have two methods on the server side that look like this:

```
var Future = require("fibers/future");

Meteor.methods({
  foo: function () {
     this.unblock();
     var f = new Future();
     setTimeout(function () {
         f.return(42);
     }, 10000);
     return f.wait();
  },
  bar: function () {
     return 43;
  }
});
```

When calling these methods from the client side (using the browser console), they work fine (`foo` waits 10 seconds and `bar` just works instantly):

```
Meteor.call("foo", function (err, data) {
   console.log(err || data);
   // After 10 seconds: 42
});

Meteor.call("bar", function (err, data) {
   console.log(err || data);
   // Very quick (*instantly*): 43
});
```

However, when having a session and we call `Meteor.logout(fn)`, the callback (`fn`), will wait after `foo` is done.

I don't want that. I want the `logout` method to work like `bar` (to not wait for the finishing of `foo`, but work instantly).

How can I do that? Is there a way to *unblock* `logout` or something similar? The login operation works in the same way (currently): it waits until `foo` sends the response.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This the expected behavior of the `logout` method. It *waits* until everything is done on the server and then logs out the user.

Supposing you're using the `accounts` package (which creates the `Accounts` global variable), you can look at the source code where [the `logout` method is defined](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/dc3cd6eb92f2bdd1bb44000cdd6abd1e5d0285b1/packages/accounts-base/accounts_client.js#L59-L76):

```
logout(callback) {
    var self = this;
    self.connection.apply('logout', [], {
      wait: true
    }, function (error, result) {
      if (error) {
        callback && callback(error);
      } else {
        self.makeClientLoggedOut();
        callback && callback();
      }
    });
}
```

If you really want the logout to work *instantly*, you can override the `Accounts.logout` function by turning off the `wait` option:

```
// Override the method and turn off the `wait` field
Accounts.logout = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.connection.apply('logout', [], {
      wait: false
    }, function (error, result) {
      if (error) {
        callback && callback(error);
      } else {
        self.makeClientLoggedOut();
        callback && callback();
      }
    });
};
```

(notice the `wait:false` in the code above)

This may crash the things (especially on the client side) because `Meteor.user()` will be `null` after logout, but this has to be tested. I expect that on the server (in the context of a server method) the `Meteor.user()` will be the right object even in the mean time the user logged out.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I misunderstand you, you just need to call `fn` *after* you've called `Meteor.logout`.  The difficulty being that this will probably run whilst the user is still logged in, which is exactly why they allow you to pass a callback.

**Calls `fn` only once `logout` completes and the user is logged out:**

`Meteor.logout(fn)`

**Calls `fn` as soon as the request to logout has been sent (at which point the user will not actually be logged out yet).**

`Meteor.logout()
fn()`